# Passing numeric variable and preventing SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection, validation

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id = $id
```

where `$id` is given from user.
I do add slashed for input variable.
Is it enough to only use `(int)$id` to prevent SQL injection? Or do I have to check `$id` with `is_numeric` before passing it to the query?

Edited: the script language is PHP.

Comment: I'd suggest adding 0 to the passed value, to ensure it is numeric.  Maybe `$value = $id + 0` and then pass `$value` to the query.  Anything to ensure that the user's raw data is not treated like a string when you want it to be a number.

Comment: Adding slashes won't help for this variable, by the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, casting a variable with `(int)` or `intval()` will ensure that it the result is only a number, and has no other characters.  This is a good method to defend against SQL injection attacks, but it only works for numeric variables of course.

For more detail on methods of SQL injection defense, see my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies), or the chapter in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Answer (score 3):

I'd give up on the idea of figuring out how to safely append a number to your query string, and instead simply move on to the idea of always using prepared statements.  They are slighly more verbose and tedious to write, but they are much safer -- and if you get into the habit, you won't have to worry about whether you did it right in this or that case, maybe sometimes it's a number, other times it's a string, did you use the right escaping mechanism?

Comment: Exactly, 100% correct. Prepared statements are the *only* comprehensive answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the $id is it an integer and is it equal to or greater than 0. Or else a user input injection attempt will most likely be at play.

Example:

$id = ( false !== ( int )$_GET[ 'id' ] >= 0 ) ? ( int )$_GET[ 'id' ] : die( header( "Location: ./index.php" ) );

Answer (score -3):

```
function mysql_prep( $value ) {
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
    if( $new_enough_php ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
        // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
        if( $magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
    } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
        // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
        if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
        // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
    }
    return $value;
}   

$username = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['username']));
```

Use that function  to be damn safe!!! :D

Comment: Any guesses how much help this is when the parameter is supposed to be *numeric*, which is what the user was asking about? You don't need to escape a parameter when it's used as a numeric value...

Comment: Numeric?? Sql injection can't be done by inputting a number! It can be done by inputting a Vulnerable STRING instead of a number.That is what the function handles.The user specifically asked for SQL injection that is why this function helps.

Comment: The parameter being submitted is being *used as a number*. You solution does not protect such a parameter when it is concatenated to a query and the submitted value was not *only* a number, but also a sql command. No quotes are needed to insert such a command here because *the parameter is being used as though it is numeric*.

Comment: true true.. ! But my code helps in preventing SQL Injections as a whole. Worrying about a number in SQL Injection is trivial i guess.Yes i agree..No quotes required for number input.

Comment: Your code does *not* protect against SQL Injection in the case the OP posts about. It escapes certain characters that *are not needed to perform SQL Injection* at all in this case. In this case, the OP needs to assure that the data submitted is numeric to prevent injection. Escapes/Quotes are *irrelevant* in this case.

Comment: Look carefully at the query being built: `SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id = $id` If I submit this value for `$id`: `1 ; DROP TABLE mytable`, your "damn safe" function does *absolutely nothing* to it, and the resulting query is: `SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id = 1 ; DROP TABLE mytable`. Notice the *complete lack* of quotes in what I have submitted. Because the value is being used as a number, it is not quoted in the concatenated string, therefore, *I don't need to submit quotes to inject SQL*.

Comment: Well all i assumed is.. There is a web form for the user to input into .So taking care that the data has been filtered correctly.Example there is an input field which value will take the place of "$id" then.. [['SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id = $id']] this query can be made malicious as [['SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id = ' or 1=1 -- ]] in this case input will be =  ' or 1=1 -- .My code helps in that.Well yeah may be he asked in different context which i didn't noticed.fine.

Comment: There's no need for a `'` in the malicious input, that's what you are not understanding. *Your code does nothing at all* in this case, because the value is being used as a number - there are no quotes involved. All I have to enter in a query box on a web page is `1 ; DROP TABLE mytable` and I have injected a drop table statement. *No quote is needed to inject here*.

Comment: In that case yeah!! Even when the user sends the binary value it is still vulnerable to sql injection.But magic quotes is a primary solution to all novice scripts and all my script does nothing but sees if it is enable..then enabling it else using other function nothing else! So kindly let me know how such attacks can be stopped?.Other than kind of prepared statements may be.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to this question. When the value is being used *as a number*, the correct solution is *not* quote escaping at all, it is verifying that the data submitted was, in fact, a number. *You are actively harming 'novices' with this advice*, because it is not correct. Escaping quotes only works for values that are handled as text values. It is completely worthless for this kind of situation.

Comment: True..for this situation yeah..I agree.In General cases.. people should rather use prepared statements i guess. Fine thanks for letting me know. :D